# On white spaces between attributes, and file size

Tags: html, formatting

So I'm learning HTML right now for project, and a friend of mine pointed out the need to not separate the following bit of code with spaces:

```
id="forms"
```

in

```
 <h2 id="forms"> Finally Something New: Forms </h2>
```

I had a look into StackOverflow and was told that adding spaces was completely fine, except that it added to file size.

My question is whether or not adding spaces within attributes is a significant addition to the file size, and my love for having things spaced out lovely will get to live another day.

Cheers:3
PS: Whee! This is my first ever StackOverflow post:3

Comment: Think of it as a byte per space, so every attribute you would be adding 2 extra bytes.  On one of my normal pages I would have hundreds of attributes so this would adding probably an extra couple of kb to the file size.  In the day of mobile browsing where everything is trying to be optimised to be smaller and faster so we don't use up all the persons download allowance or their download speed may not be great, a couple of kb can make a big difference.  Also if other developers work on this, they would probably hate you for doing it

Comment: Ahahaha, thanks:3 I'll get rid of the spaces then:3